# Approximation of Normal to Binomial

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, approximation, binomial-distribution

I am currently reading Feller's "Introduction to Probabilty theory"... Please, can you help me to understand a part of his normal approximation to binomial?

For simplicity he took the case of $n=2v$ trials and $v+k$ successes, with $P(Success)=1/2$. Hence,

$a_k=Binom(v+k, 2v, 1/2)$, then he reasoned, that from the definiton

$a_k=a_0 \frac{v(v-1)...(v-k+1)}{(v+1)(v+2)...(v+k)}$

***Then the part that I can't understand***: He divided the numerator and denominator by $v^k$ and claimed that the individual factors take on the form $1 + j/v$ with $j$  running from $-(k-1)$ to $k$. 
***Why did he divided and how it was done***? He did it to get:

$1+ \frac{j}{v}=e^{(j/v)+...} $, which I understand, but how he came to this point?

Comment: At the moment it is hard to answer this without the notation being clarified. What are $v$, and $a_k$? Further, if there are n trials, there cannot be $n+k$ successes; please can you check your notation.

Comment: @owen88 I changed B to Binomial so I assume the $a_k$ is clear. I am sorry, I forgot to mention, that $k$ is ranging from $-v$ to $v$. $v$ is just a notation to show, that the number of all trials is even: $n=2*v$

Comment: Ok; this is a bit clearer, but in the line "For simplicity..." it still doesn't make sense to have "n=2v" and then $n+k$ successes.

Comment: I changed the notation

Comment: There is still an error; in the line "For simplicity..." if shoul be $\nu + k$ trials.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the equation connecting $a_n$ with $a_0$, the numerator $v(v-1)\cdots(v-k+1)$ has $k$ factors. (I'm writing $v$ instead of $\nu$ to save typing.)   Feller divides each factor by its own copy of $v$, getting (after division) $(v/v) ((v-1)/v) \cdots((v-k+1)/v) = 1 (1-1/v) \cdots (1-(k-1)/v)$.  Simlarly, the denominator $(v+1)(v+2)\cdots(v+k)$ has $k$ factors, each of which he divides by $v$ to obtain $((v+1)/v)((v+2)/v)\cdots ((v+k)/v) = (1+1/v)(1+2/v)\cdots(1+k/v)$.

Maybe it's clearer with a slight change of notation:$$
v (v-1) \cdots(v-k+1) =\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (v-j)=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} v\left(1-\frac j v\right)=  v^k \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(1-\frac j v\right)$$
for the numerator, and so on.

*Why* does he do this?  It's a kind of factorization: both numerator and denominator are products of quantities close to the big quantity $v$, so he factors out the big $v^k$ from both numerator and denominator, leaving a product of numbers close to $1$.

Continuing, to fill in gaps suggested by the comments: the ratio $a_k/a_0$ is given by the product
$$ \frac{a_k}{a_0} = \frac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(1-\frac j v\right)}{\prod_{j=1}^{k} \left(1+\frac j v\right)}$$
 $$=\exp\left( \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \log\left(1-\frac j v\right)-\sum_{j=1}^{k}\log \left(1+\frac j v\right)\right)\approx\exp\left( \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} -\frac j v-\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac j v \right). $$
Here the basic approximation is $\log(1+t)=t +O(t^2)$. After summation over $t=\pm j/v$ for $j=1,2,\dots k$, the error from the $O(t^2)$ term is $\sum_{j=1}^k O((j/v)^2) = O(k^3/v^2)$, which I'm sure Feller accounts for. (I'm writing from memory: my Feller is at the office just now.) The main term in the exponent is 
$$ \left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} -\frac j v\right)-\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac j v \right)= -\frac 1 v \left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} j + \sum_{j=1}^{k} j \right) = -\frac 1 v \left( \frac {k(k-1} 2 + \frac {k(k+1)}2\right) = - \frac {k^2} v.$$
This is why Feller approximates $a_k\approx a_0 \exp(-k^2/v)$.

Comment: Please, would you be so kind to help me to continue? After making this changes Feller suggested to use it to get $a_k~a_0e^{-k^2/v}$. I computed it 3 times and every time get $a_k~a_0e^{k/v}$. Here is what I did: $a_k=a_0 \frac {e^{(-1/v+...+(-(k-1)/v)}} {e^{(1/v+...+k/v)}}=a_0e^{\frac 1 v (\sum_{0}^{k-1}j- \sum_{1}^{k}i )}=a_0e^{k/v}$, since all terms cancel except 0 and $-k$.

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully to your satisfaction.  I think you were missing the approximation $1/(1+j/v)\approx 1-j/v)$, or, equivalently, you were multiplying numerator and denominator instead of dividing.

Answer (score 0):

In the same fashion I want to argue about the limiting form of the eqn. 2.2 (feller) i.e.

$a_{k}=a_{0}\frac{v(v-1)...(v-k+1)}{(v+1)(v+2)...(v+k)}=a_{0}.\frac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (1-\frac{j}{v})}{\prod_{j=1}^{k} (1+\frac{j}{v})}$

The limiting form is=

$a_{0}.\frac{\lim_{v\to\infty}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (1-\frac{j}{v})}{\lim_{v\to\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{k} (1+\frac{j}{v})}=a_{0}$

though $\frac{j}{v}=0$ as $v$ tends to infinity.